# Redefining access for overloaded functions in child class

Tags: c++, access-modifiers

Assuming I have following Parent class

```
class Animal {
private:
//member variables here
public:

    void print() {
        cout << "Overloaded print with no param \n";
    }

    void print(int i) {
        cout << "Overloaded  print with int param\n";
    }
};
```

And I have another class inheriting from it.. and I want to redefine access to make the first overloaded function to be protected, while making the other private utilizing `using` declaration as following, but compiler emits error when trying to provide a parameter-ized version of the function.

```
class Dog: private Animal {


protected:
    using Animal::print; 

};
```

So, is that possible in C++, and if yes, how to do it ?

Thanks

Comment: There's no point; you can always call these functions through a pointer (or reference) to the base class.

Comment: It is not possible, you can only either redefine access to all overloads or to none.

Comment: @molbdnilo, That's true for public inheritance only. But won't work for another types.

Comment: If you're not using public inheritance, don't ask a question with public inheritance.

Comment: @molbdnilom OKay you are right. I changed the question